# Ultra-lightweight RSS indicator for Ubuntu, running as status menu indicator

Tags: open-source, ubuntu, rss

I use [Feedindicator](http://code.google.com/p/feedindicator/) to be alerted of new RSS news.
It is perfect for me in terms of UI, but it [freezes randomly](http://code.google.com/p/feedindicator/issues/detail?id=28), making it unusable for me.

Is there any similar software for Ubuntu Unity?

- Run as an Ubuntu Unity status menu indicator
- Color changes when there is a new item
- Clicking on an item marks it as read and opens my favorite browser on that item's link
- Possibility to mark all items as read from the UI
- Possibility to add a feed from the UI
- Support for Atom and most RSS formats
- Must be Open Source

I am open to other concepts, but anyway here is how Feedindicator looks like:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thunderbird! It only consumes 1 GB of RAM. :D I know people who are happy with Akregator.